# How do you decode a begin ... vault "code" or hack?

Tags: security

So, there's an Easter Egg "hacking" hunt going on.

I've decoded 4 out of 5, except 3rd one,
which has this text:

```
begin 644 vault
+=&AE<F]O=&-O;@H`
`
end
```

Where do I even begin with this? 
What language is this?

Sorry, I'm no hacker. But I'm finding the challenges rather fun, because it involves html, braille, cookies, and image deciphering. It's this last one I can't figure out.

Comment: Whatever that is, is encoded. I would start by printing the ASCII code for these weird characters and then continue my investigation from there.

Comment: Thanks, Femaref. Got it! For those of you who are bored, you can have a try at the contest I'm participating in: http://easteregg.rootcon.org/

Comment: @geff_chang you can thank him by selecting his answer as the official problem solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a hint: UUDecode/UUEncode.